# How to recursively list files (and only files) in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

**Wanted:**

I want a listing of files with full paths listed out recursively in Windows 7 through the command prompt.

I DON'T want folders to be listed.

**Attempt:**

This got me all files, but also included the directories:

`dir /b /a /s`

**Result:**

```
C:\path1
C:\path1\file1.txt
C:\path1\path2
C:\path1\path2\file2.txt
```

**Desired Output:**

```
C:\path1\file1.txt
C:\path1\path2\file2.txt
```

**Other Thoughts:**

I'm thinking I could do a loop (here's some psuedo-code):

`for /f %a in ('dir /b /a /s') do if something then @echo %~a endif`

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using WIndows 7

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`dir /A-D /S /B` will produce the result you want:

[image]

```
C:\>dir /?
(...)
/A          Displays files with specified attributes.
attributes   D  Directories                R  Read-only files
             H  Hidden files               A  Files ready for archiving
             S  System files               I  Not content indexed files
             L  Reparse Points             O  Offline files
             -  Prefix meaning not
```